# Nikon D750 Auto focus

Tags: focusing

Hi I have just bought a used D750 and am just finding my way around the controls. I have been trying to pot the Auto Focus to AF-C but the following message appears in the panel "This option  is not availableat current settings or in the cameras current state" I have tried to change it in the custom settings menu and by pressing the AF button and turning the command wheel. This will only allow me to go from AF-A to AF-S.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you done a reset to defaults (see page 199 in the manual)?

Comment: Similar, possibly related question (probably not a duplicate though): [Why is my Nikon D750 not autofocusing?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/86260)

Comment: Thanks for that I have done a reset and will continue to work through the settings.

Answer (score 1):

To use autofocus, rotate the focus-mode selector to AF. Autofocus mode can be selected by pressing the AF mode button and rotating the main command dial until the desired setting is displayed in the viewfinder or control panel.

Procedure
Press the i button.
Highlight the current focus mode in the information display with the multi selector and press OK.
Highlight AF-C and press OK.

[image]